# Can I boot to a different Mac OS X partition from the command line?

Tags: macos, mac, multi-boot

I need to test some software (nightly) on 3 Mac OS X versions: 10.4, 10.5, 10.6 -- the software interfaces with the hardware, so non-native solutions (like virtualisation) are not ideal.

So I figured the best way to test the software (which is automatic by the way) is to have a partition for each version of the OS. This way I can boot to a specific version to test the software.

This needs to be done on a timed schedule, so I was hoping I could run a command like this in a crontab:

```
reboot --to "Mac OS X 10.5"
```

Is something like this possible, or do I need to write my own software to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not aware of any application that can do this, but doing some research there is 2 suggestions.

Firstly use AppleScript to [select the startup disk](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20070126131322301). The basic idea is using the following you can select the boot partition and then reboot.

> do shell script "bless -mount \"/Volumes/Name of the drive\" -setBoot"
>    with administrator privileges
>   do shell script "shutdown -r now" with administrator privileges.

You can then use `osascript` to execute the above AppleScript from your `crontab`.

Alternatively you can install [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) which allows you to select an OS at boot, and potentially modify the startup files using a bash command which can change the default OS to boot. I have no way to confirm this can be done but it is an option.

*The above is shown as an AppleScript, and since the source article refers to it I am keeping it in the original format, however as was pointed out in the comments, the two commands can be run in the shell directly without needing AppleScript*

Comment: There's no reason to (and good reasons not to) use a shell script to run AppleScript to run a shell script...  This is especially likely to fail when run from crontab.  Instead, just put `bless -mount "/Volumes/Name of the drive" -setBoot && shutdown -r now` directly in a shell script, and run that via crontab.

Comment: @Gordon Davisson This should be an answer; I would have accepted it. I will accept Diago's instead.

Comment: I found one caveat; you'll need to run it as the root user.

Answer (score 1):

The [`nvram`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/nvram.8.html) command will allow you to modify the NVRAM parameter that specifies which partition to boot from.

Comment: Although it looks like `bless` as given in Diago's answer will do a better job of it.